# Google Maps polylines not displaying at all

Tags: javascript, r, google-maps, google-visualization

I have generated some Javascript using the googleVis package for R.  When I do so, the polylines do not display.  I've tried various browsers and it fails in all of them.  I am going to show you first some minimalist R code, which generates the problem. I'm then going to show you the HTML/Javascript it creates.  Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong and what the fix might be.

The R code

```
 require(googleVis)
 df <- data.frame(Postcode =      c("77003","08540","80545"),Tip=c("Houston","Princeton","Red Feather Lakes"))
 M <- gvisMap(df, "Postcode", "Tip",
          options=list(showLine=TRUE,lineWidth=20,lineColor='red'))
 plot(M)
 cat(unlist(M))
```

The resulting HTML/Javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>MapID88977a251b2</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
  color: #444444;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 75%;
  }
  a {
  color: #4D87C7;
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Map generated in R 3.2.2 by googleVis 0.5.10 package -->
<!-- Mon Sep  7 16:32:28 2015 -->


<!-- jsHeader -->
<script type="text/javascript">

// jsData 
function gvisDataMapID88977a251b2 () {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var datajson =
[
 [
 "77003",
"Houston" 
],
[
 "08540",
"Princeton" 
],
[
 "80545",
"Red Feather Lakes" 
] 
];
data.addColumn('string','Postcode');
data.addColumn('string','Tip');
data.addRows(datajson);
return(data);
}

// jsDrawChart
function drawChartMapID88977a251b2() {
var data = gvisDataMapID88977a251b2();
var options = {};
options["showTip"] = true;
options["showLine"] = true;
options["lineWidth"] =     20;
options["lineColor"] = "red";


    var chart = new google.visualization.Map(
    document.getElementById('MapID88977a251b2')
    );
    chart.draw(data,options);


}


// jsDisplayChart
(function() {
var pkgs = window.__gvisPackages = window.__gvisPackages || [];
var callbacks = window.__gvisCallbacks = window.__gvisCallbacks || [];
var chartid = "map";

// Manually see if chartid is in pkgs (not all browsers support Array.indexOf)
var i, newPackage = true;
for (i = 0; newPackage && i < pkgs.length; i++) {
if (pkgs[i] === chartid)
newPackage = false;
}
if (newPackage)
  pkgs.push(chartid);

// Add the drawChart function to the global list of callbacks
callbacks.push(drawChartMapID88977a251b2);
})();
function displayChartMapID88977a251b2() {
  var pkgs = window.__gvisPackages = window.__gvisPackages || [];
  var callbacks = window.__gvisCallbacks = window.__gvisCallbacks || [];
  window.clearTimeout(window.__gvisLoad);
  // The timeout is set to 100 because otherwise the container div we are
  // targeting might not be part of the document yet
  window.__gvisLoad = setTimeout(function() {
  var pkgCount = pkgs.length;
  google.load("visualization", "1", { packages:pkgs, callback: function() {
  if (pkgCount != pkgs.length) {
  // Race condition where another setTimeout call snuck in after us; if
  // that call added a package, we must not shift its callback
  return;
}
while (callbacks.length > 0)
callbacks.shift()();
} });
}, 100);
}

// jsFooter
</script>

<!-- jsChart -->  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?callback=displayChartMapID88977a251b2"></script>

<!-- divChart -->

<div id="MapID88977a251b2" 
  style="width: 500; height: automatic;">
</div>
 <div><span>Data: df &#8226; Chart ID: <a href="Chart_MapID88977a251b2.html">MapID88977a251b2</a> &#8226; <a href="https://github.com/mages/googleVis">googleVis-0.5.10</a></span><br /> 
<!-- htmlFooter -->
<span> 
  R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) 
  &#8226; <a href="https://developers.google.com/terms/">Google Terms of Use</a> &#8226; <a href="https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map">Documentation and Data Policy</a>
</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

As it seems the documentation is incorrect:

> `lineWidth`
>
> If `showLine` is true, defines the line width (in pixels).
>   **Type:** number
>   **Default:** 10

The option `lineWidth` seems to be ignored, instead set an (currently undocumented) option `lineWeight` (it doesn't default to `10`, so you must set this option...to a number>0)

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["map"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);
function drawMap() {
var arr = [
['postcode','name'],
 [
 "77003",
"Houston" 
],
[
 "08540",
"Princeton" 
],
[
 "80545",
"Red Feather Lakes" 
] 
]
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);
    var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));
    map.draw(data, { showLine: true,lineWeight:20,lineColor:'red',enableScrollWheel:true});

}
```

```css
html,body,#map_div{
height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="map_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks you.  You are in my will!